# How to find the address of the owner a of smart contract if it does not have any owner description

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-deployment, addresses

How to find the address of the owner of a smart contract if it does not have any owner-related description like no address assignment, for instance how to find the owner of the following smart contract?

```
contract C {
   function pay(uint n, address d){
   d.send(n);
}
```

Somebody, please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: Do you want to find out whi deployed,  or who owns the smart contract? Because those two are not always the same.

Comment: @Sky I want the address for the owner which is initialized in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no owner in your given contract, literally `everyone` is the owner as everyone can send the balance to anywhere using `pay`. If you refer the `owner` to be the `deployer` then it's the one who deploy the contract, however `deployer` is different from `owner` most of the time. If the contract has source code you can check if it implements [Openzeppelin Ownable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol) or some similar patterns.
If there is no source code, it will be a bit difficult but still doable by either 1 of the two methods:

1. Tracing the privilege function call: you can get to the point that there is an address check (e.g. get the full execution trace of the transaction to `pay()` and analyze it). You probably see the comparison `msg.sender` and `owner` in evm bytecode.
2. Track all existing transactions to the deployed contract on blockchain, the tx call to privilege actions is usually originated from the `owner` address.

Comment: what is this address? obj = await C.new(); console.log(obj.address); Is obj.address is the address of owner?

Comment: @Sky Is the above owner address?

Comment: that is the contract address after deployment, it's what you need to send transaction to to interact with the code. E.g. you will send tx stating that you want to call function `pay()` to the address you got from `obj.address`

Comment: To make it clearer, I recommend reading : https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/deploying-and-interacting and all related documents about smart contracts